# How to receive a callback from Soundcloud when connecting by Unity for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, soundcloud

I have an app made in Unity that let you mix a song. I'm working on a "upload to Soundcloud" button to include in this app for both Android and iOS.

I have trouble receiving a response from Soundcloud after directing the user to the "Connect" window of SoundCloud. I use something like this to open the Soundcloud connection page. The browser is opened correctly and I can sign in using this.

```
    Application.OpenURL("https://soundcloud.com/connect?"
            + "client_id=[my_client_id]"
            + "&redirect_uri=my.app://callback"
            + "&display=popup"      
            + "&response_type=token"
            + "&scope=non-expiring");
```

I have created a custom scheme for both my iOS and Android app to redirect to my app after the connection. That is working too, my app is reopened after clicking on "Connect" in the Soundcloud page.

I now need an authentication code or token to request an access token to be able to upload my song. But after being redirect in my app, I don't know what to do to receive the authentication code. It must have something to do with the ://callback link, but I didn't find how to get it. Do I need to make platform specific code for that?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks SteveE for your reply but it wasn't my problem.

The problem was that I needed a Deep Linking implementation for both my Android and iOS app to receive the callback from Soundcloud. I needed something to catch the intent in the onCreate method, which contains the data send by Soundcloud, on Android and to catch the calls to application:openURL:options: du UIApplicationDelegate on iOS.

To do this, we needed native plugins for both platforms and now we can receive the Soundcloud callback and check our authorization code to continue the process of uploading the song.

Answer (score 0):

The callback should include a code for you to use to create a token

The callback URL when called will have a code attached to it :

http://YOUR_CALLBACK_URL?code=CODE_RETURNED_FROM_SOUNDCLOUD

Once you have extracted the code returned from the url, you can then use that to make a request to soundcloud to get an authorization token

Example request using curl (using PHP)

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token' 
-F 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID' 
-F 'client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET' 
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' 
-F 'redirect_uri=YOUR_CALLBACK_URL' 
-F 'code=THE_VALUE_OF_THE_CODE_RETURNED'


$data = array(
  'code' => VALUE_OF_THE_CODE_RETURNED,
  'client_id' => YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  'client_secret' => YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  'redirect_uri' => YOUR_CALLBACK_URL,
  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
);
```

I use the following options with curl

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

If successful you should receive something like this (example is JSON)

```
{
"access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE",
"expires_in":21599,
"scope":"*",
"refresh_token":"REFRESH_TOKEN_VALUE"
}
```